# How do I include a previously declared function as a value in a key-value pair in an object constructor?

Tags: javascript, function, key-value, object-construction

The task:

1. declare a variable called myName that returns an array of two elements, firstname and last name.
2. declare a function called join(), it will return the two elements as a string with a space between each element.
3. declare a function createProfile that should expect an array "name" as input(???).
4. createProfile creates and returns an object with two key-value pairs.
   key: name
   value: use the function "join()" and the parameter "name" variable to return a string with your full name, separated by a space

   `key`: email
   `value`: my email as a string.
5. Declare a variable called myProfile and assign the result of calling createProfile with myName.

The problem is in step 4. 
I believe I should use an object constructor. 
I don't know how to properly include the function join() a value in a key-value pair in an object constructor.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
const myName = ["firstname", "lastname"];

function join(){
    document.write("Hello, my name is " + myName[0] + " " + myName[1] + ".");
};

join();


function createProfile(name, email){
    this.name = function(){
        return this.join();
    };
    this.email = email;
    return this;
}

let myProfile = new createProfile(name,"me@gmail.com");
console.log(myProfile);
```

Expected results:
calling create profile should log an object with my full name as a string, and my email address as a string.

Actual results:

```
createProfile {name: ƒ, email: "hotcoffeehero@gmail.com"}
email: "hotcoffeehero@gmail.com"
name: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

The value of name is an empty function.

How do I display it as a string?

Onegai Shimasu

Comment: First you do not have `join` on `this`. Second, you can look into `getter` properties for that

Comment: function createProfile(name, email){
    this.name = function(){
        return this.join();
    };  I thought that is what this was doing.

Comment: If I understand correct, all you have to do is `createProfile(join(), 'email')` and in function, `this.name = name`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your logic, you need fix the code with the next code

```
const myName = ["firstname", "lastname"];

function join(){
    //document.write("Hello, my name is " + myName[0] + " " + myName[1] + ".");
    return myName[0] + ' ' + myName[1] // You only return the values
};

join();


function createProfile(name, email){
    this.name = join(); // you call the function and assing to name
    this.email = email;
    return this;
}

const myProfile = new createProfile(name,"me@gmail.com");
console.log(myProfile);
```

but there are better ways to development this

Comment: Thanks David! That is really helpful. It is intentionally convoluted code. The task is actually the application for an immersive coding program so they made it like this on purpose. I was having trouble with that one part. Cheers!